# How to avoid pip listing pre-release versions?

Tags: python, pip

pip has an option (`--pre`) to install pre-release/dev versions.
When trying to install a non-existing release (package==bogusversion), pip will output a list of all available versions. BUT, even without `--pre`, that list includes pre-release versions.
Is this avoidable?

Example:

```
pip install elasticsearch==notreallyaversion 2>&1 | grep -o "\(from versions: .*\)"
from versions: 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 6.0.0, 6.1.1, 6.2.0, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.8.0, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.0.4, 7.0.5, 7.1.0, 7.5.1, 7.6.0a1)
```

7.6.0a1 is listed, even though I didn't use `--pre`.

Comment: I used a workaround by piping the output into some grep/sed/etc to exclude non final release versions.